# How does the Minimum spanning tree in neo4j work

Tags: neo4j, graph-theory, graph-algorithm, minimum-spanning-tree

I am playing around with some graph theory algorithms in neo4j. I am trying to find the minimum spanning tree (mst) within my network. I synthetically created a network of 10 000 people. Each person has 12 relationship types each one linking him back to the other 9999 and each relationship with its own weight assigned.

The problem I have however is the fact that according to the definition the results must be a tree spanning over the ENTIRE network. The neo4j function however only returns a very small sub-graph (only about 12 nodes) of the entire network.

The code I am using looks like this:

```
MATCH (a:Name {Name:"Dillon Snow"})
CALL algo.mst(a,"Weight",{stats:true})
YIELD loadMillis, computeMillis, writeMillis, weightSum, weightMin, weightMax, relationshipCount
RETURN loadMillis, computeMillis, writeMillis, weightSum, weightMin, weightMax, relationshipCount
```

What can I change to get the function to return the mst spreading through the entire network

Answer (score 0):

`algo.mst.*` has not been adapted to the matured Neo4j-Graph-Algorithms-CoreAPI in its current release (3.2.5.2/3.3.0.0 @ Dec 2017) which might lead to unexpected results. But there is a pull request in the pipe, you can expect some changes in the next release.

Anyway.. The procedure should add a new relationship-type (default `mst`) to your nodes. In a connected graph each node should be connected as well while a disconnected graph leads to connections only between the nodes of this particular connected component (from your startNode).

If i understand you right you have multiple relationship **types** and more then one of them between a pair of nodes? E.g. Node A is connected to Node B with several relations, each of them with a different type and property value. This is a problem. In general the Graph-Algorithms-API does not support multible releationships. **Each pair of nodes can only have one connection per direction.** Although you can import multible types the core-api itself has no idea of the underlying type. If multible relationships between a pair of nodes get imported usualy the last one wins. This has been mentioned in the documentation ;)

To overcome this limitation you could replace your relationship types with some kind of artificial nodes. When traversing over the result tree the occurence of one of those nodes would indicate the original relationship.

Comment: Thank you for the Comment, The thing is I read that the multiple relationships could have a problem so I tried to correct this by creating only one relationship but with different attributes. For example all my relationships are called `Is connected to` but some have the attribute `works with` some `friends with` and each relationship has its own `weight` characteristic. This made a lot of the other graph theory functions easier, but not the mst. The second thing 95% of my network only has one relationship between the nodes. This means that the at least 50% of the network should be connected

Comment: The limitation also exists for properties. Basically the GA-CoreApi reduces all Labels, RelationTypes and also property types to one. Anyway the current implementation is broken.

Comment: So as i said you can either wait for the next release or this [pull request](https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-graph-algorithms/pull/511)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help really appreciate it